# Efficient workflow/tools for converting color images to hex arrays

Tags: programming, c, display, linux, oled

I would like to display 65k color animated gifs on my oled. I'm using the adafruit library for https://learn.adafruit.com/096-mini-color-oled
Now I need to convert a significant number of images to hex arrays. I found a couple of tools that can deal with monochrome images and I found this: https://www.digole.com/tools/PicturetoC_Hex_converter.php which might work for individual images, but is impractical for batch processing. I also found this, but it appears to also be intended for individual images and doesn't simply work in wine. So isn't there some linux commandline magic to do that?

Comment: You could have a look at ImageMagick. I think you want to export the image as RGB565 format. This will give you raw bytes. So you can use, for example, `xxd` to convert this to hex. Not sure what you mean with hex array.

Comment: your question is not about the arduino, so it does not belong here .... it may be a better fit at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola "Arduino Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino." - my question is about how to convert graphics to an arduino compatible format to use in programming it. IMO it's covered under questions regarding "software that is compatible with Arduino". WIth that being said, I already got my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this plugin to be satisfactory: https://khalim19.github.io/gimp-plugin-export-layers/
It's not a single elegant command, but is quite fast and maybe can be optimized with some scripting.